# MERN Stack hosting on Vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, vercel

I'm trying to host the MERN stack project which is on GitHub. While hosting the stack, I am getting an error of hosting my application on Vercel. My folder structure is similar to this:

```
client
  node_modules
  public
  src
  .gitignore
  package-lock.json
  package.json

server
  node_modules
  app/model
  app/routes
  .env
  .gitignore
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  server.js
```

Is there a way to host the backend and frontend on the same project using the vercel.json configuration file? If not, then is there a way to make 2 projects (one for the frontend and the other for the backend) using the same GitHub repo?

Thank you